# Hiding section vertically and horizontally using Flex without manually calculating percentage

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've small problem with hiding sections when they have titles placed on their left side.

[image]

Once you close section (Hide) the top one behaves correctly, however the bottom one when hidden leaves everything in place.

[image]

And I would like it to behave in a way where it hides completely just leaving title header within section.

[image]

I can fix it by adding `style="flex-basis: 1.4%;"` to line 593 so code:

```html
        <div class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden">
            <div class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden">
                <div class="defaultSection-79s53o1 overflowHidden">
                    <div class="defaultSectionHead-79s53o1">
```

changes to:

```html
        <div class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden">
            <div class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden" style="flex-basis: 1.4%;">
                <div class="defaultSection-79s53o1 overflowHidden">
                    <div class="defaultSectionHead-79s53o1">
```

I'm basically overwriting flex-basis value in class FlexElement

```css
            .flexElement {
                flex-basis: 100%;
            }
```

While this works it's of course subject to not be really dynamic. If there's more text, the text is bigger or there are more sections next to each other that will be hidden I guess things will go sideways and my 1.4% will not work. So what would be the proper way to do this so it works for both vertical and horizontal hiding of sections?

Here's an example with 3 sections

[image]

Which requires 2.8% - `<div class="defaultSection-svy0khb overflowHidden" style="flex-basis: 2.8%;">` to work.

Here's full code:

https://codepen.io/MadBoyEvo/pen/gOrayWL

Comment: *to line 593 so code:* --> so you expect us to read at least 600 lines of code?

Comment: No - but I can't minimize example further because it wouldn't show what I need to show. Relevant code is between 592 to 598. Of course I can cut and paste 10-15 lines but without full context they will be pretty much meaningless.

Comment: Use ```calc``` in css

Comment: @RayeesAC Well, the thing is I am not sure what parameters to choose into calculation. It's only 1.4 for one, and 1.4 for 2, but if things change on screen, as in things will be smaller, larger I'm pretty sure this 1.4 per section can become 2.0 per section.

Comment: Please put a [mcve] of the code *in the question itself*.

Comment: I'll try to to cut down the code to minimum.

Comment: @MadBoy For what it's worth your CodePen's code is currently not too much to fit in a Stack Snippet in the post, by a long shot. And there's lots you can remove and still reproduce the issue, based on my initial glance at the code.

Comment: Trimmed it down a bit.

Comment: To be clear, when I said "in the question itself" in italics, I meant here on Stack Overflow, the code should exist in the body of your question; per the rules, a link to CodePen *only* is not adequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated

You should make the container hasn't a width value if it collapsed. In your case, remove the **width** value from `.defaultSection-79s53o1` then add the width value once you need to show the data. Add a class `.--show` contains a width value, the class toggled in the `show` and `hide` functions. For the original example [codepen](https://codepen.io/abdelrhman-m27/pen/XWdaaJY).

For multiple panels, remove the **width** on `.defaultSection-*` classes and add default classes `.--hide` for toggling panels and a default `.--show` class on the static panel. You can check a live example [codepen](https://codepen.io/abdelrhman-m27/pen/BaKddwW).

```
.--show {
  width: 100%;
}

.--hide {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 1.4rem;
}
```

In **show** function:

```
document.getElementById(obj).parentNode.classList.add('--show');
document.getElementById(obj).parentNode.classList.remove('--hide');
```

In **hide** function:

```
document.getElementById(obj).parentNode.classList.remove('--show');
document.getElementById(obj).parentNode.classList.add('--hide');
```

Comment: I checked codepen and it doesn't do anything? I added your code into my local code - no change either :/

Comment: @MadBoy The Codepen didn't change your version, I create a new one on my profile. Please check it in the answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I just wonder will it scale automatically for 2,3,5,X panels? Or that `width: calc(100% - 10px);` in --show has to be adjusted? Or how does it work?

Comment: @MadBoy No, I didn't change this width value and it doesn't matter if you using `width: 100%;` because the wrapper has two elements only. I don't think this value participate with multiple panels. I think you need to use **n** in `calc` with a percentage value. Anyways, we can make it dynamic if you want :D

Comment: Ye, I need it to be dynamic as I have no clue whether it will be 1,5,10,15 elements.

Comment: @MadBoy Can you create another example contains 3 or 5 panels to try on it?

Comment: Will try to. Please give me some time - I've broken generator so need to fix it first.

Comment: @MadBoy I added another example with multiple panels and improved the classes a bit. Also, I changed the code snippets in the answer to arrange the multiple panels approach. You can check it above...

Comment: https://codepen.io/MadBoyEvo/pen/xxVLXVw - here's new codepen with only sections - lots of them in different scenarios

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220762/discussion-between-abdelrhman-arnos-and-madboy).

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
flex-basis: calc( 1.4 * n );
```

more about `calc` refer this :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: It won't solve my issue. The value 1.4% is not static. For 3 sections next to each other I've to use `style="flex-basis: calc(1.0% * 3);"` for 1 it's 1.4%. And if some other conditions will change it's gonna blow up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```css
  min-width: auto;
  flex-basis: 0;
```

Or the other way around.

Ultimately, you will have to find your own solution based on what you want exactly. Try playing around with properties such as, `flex-basis, flex-grow, flex-shring, width, min-width, max-width`. You can achieve what you want mostly with only these properties.

If you create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell clearly how you want it to work, I could help you more.